# JS Loop through an array of objects of an array of objects to delete entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array like so:

```js
const array = [
    {
        '12345': [
            {
                name: 'item one',
                numbers: ['12345', '77484'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item two',
                numbers: ['12345', '65456'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item three',
                numbers: ['12345', '33920'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item four',
                numbers: ['12345', '99393'],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        '67890': [
            {
                name: 'item one b',
                numbers: ['67890', '33232'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item two b',
                numbers: ['67890', '33456'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item three b',
                numbers: ['67890', '77665'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item four b',
                numbers: ['67890', '11234'],
            },
        ],
    },
]
console.log(array);
```

If I am given a name as a dynamic variable, for example, 'item three b', how can find that name inside the array of objects of the array of objects to delete it?

I'm stumped when trying to get into the nested array.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: With either a nested loop or `map` of `find`, you could get the object.
What are you then wanting to do with it? Delete it? That makes it a bit different.

Comment: Hi, yes. if I am given a name, such as `item three b`, how do I find it in the nested array and delete it. Thanks. I've tried `find()` but I cannot get into the nested array with `find()`. I can loop through the first level of objects, but I am stumped when getting into the nested array.

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole property that contains the name, or just the individual array element.

Comment: I would delete the whole object that contians the name. `{ name: item three b, numbers: ['67890', '77665'] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using forEach loop , then using findIndex and finally splice the data from the array.

```js
const array = [
    {
        '12345': [
            {
                name: 'item one',
                numbers: ['12345', '77484'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item two',
                numbers: ['12345', '65456'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item three',
                numbers: ['12345', '33920'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item four',
                numbers: ['12345', '99393'],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        '67890': [
            {
                name: 'item one b',
                numbers: ['67890', '33232'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item two b',
                numbers: ['67890', '33456'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item three b',
                numbers: ['67890', '77665'],
            },
            {
                name: 'item four b',
                numbers: ['67890', '11234'],
            },
        ],
    },
]

array.forEach(obj => {
   Object.values(obj).forEach(ob => {
   var index = ob.findIndex(o => o.name==='item three b');
   if(index>-1){
      ob.splice(index,1);
     }
  })
})

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This worked like an absolute charm! Thank you so much!